# Best method to trigger partition pruning in Oracle for a non-contiguous partition range

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I have a number of large Oracle tables partitioned by day of year; data older than 1 year is deleted to keep each partition to a maximum size. We run a lot of different queries on ranges of time, where these large tables are joined. We have to handle the case where the time range crosses the year-end boundary, causing the beginning day of year to be larger than the ending day of year.

What we've tried:

```
WHERE table1.doy IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(doy_tbl)) AND
      table1.time BETWEEN time1 AND time2 AND
      table2.doy = table1.doy
```

where doy_tbl is an array we just created that has all the possible values of doy (for example 365, 366, 1, 2).

This seems like it should trigger partition pruning, but doesn't. Based on the execution plan, it filters based on this IN at the end, after all the other joins are complete, even if the `PUSH_SUBQ` hint is used. `table` is pruned thanks to the remaining conditions, but `table1` never is.

Another attempt was something like this:

```
WHERE (table1.doy BETWEEN doy_min AND doy_max OR
       (doy_min > doy_max AND table1.doy NOT BETWEEN doy_max AND doy_min))
```

That seemed to sort of work (table1 said KEY(OR) in it's exec plan) but some tables in the join were not pruned. Is there a way to restructure this such that it would work, other than wrapping it in an IF and splitting it into 2 queries and bloating all the stored procedures?

The other method was, when crossing the year boundary, doing 2 queries, one from 365-366 and one from 1-2, and then just using:

```
WHERE table1.doy BETWEEN doy_min AND doy_max
```

This worked (all tables were accessed with KEY(AP)) but once again this bloats the code. In the situation where we have 100's of these stored procedures, it's not very desirable.

Is there a way I'm missing to make the first 2 methods work? Or some other graceful method to handle this situation that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Is the table partitioned just on `doy`, a numeric column between 1 and 366?  Is there a reason that you chose that rather than partitioning on an actual `date` column?  What is Oracle's cardinality estimate for the array (which I'm guessing is really a nested table or an associative array not a varray)?  Have you tried adding a cardinality hint to the query against the collection?

Comment: What happens when you substitute "SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(doy_tbl)" with "365, 366, 1, 2" - just to see if this works. If so, we can perhaps explore this avenue further.